# TextInput /Input element looses focus on key press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently developing an application using React Native.

This trial app has a component that has a TextInput and two buttons (ADD and DELETE).

When I press the ADD Button, a new component appears. If I press the DELETE Button that the same component disappears.

The screen is like the photo bellow:
[image]

I control the TextInput with the index which is the same number as the index of the component.

---

My question is: why can't I enter some text as usual in this code?

I have to focus the cursor every time I enter 1 word.

I lose a flashing vertical bar(I check in the photo below) in the input area every time I press a key.
[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

And, I want to control the inputted value from TextInput with array[] not object{} because in case of an array is easier to delete a component sliding index and value like an explanation below:
[image]

I have no idea to control index and value with an, object and it's complicated for my skill now, but if there are some nice ways to resolve using object, I hope to know it.

---

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function Item({ number, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={number[index]}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleInput(index, e.nativeEvent.text);
        }}
      ></TextInput>
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function TestStateArray() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState([]);

  function handleAdd() {
    setCount((v) => v + 1);
  }

  function handleDelete(index) {
    setCount((v) => v - 1);
    setNumber((v) => {
      const ret = v.slice();
      ret.splice(index, 1);
      return ret;
    });
  }

  function handleInput(index, text) {
    setNumber((v) => {
      const ret = v.slice();
      ret[index] = text;
      return ret;
    });
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => (
        <Item
          number={number}
          handleInput={handleInput}
          handleAdd={handleAdd}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          key={i + "-" + number}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
  },
});
```

---

After I have some answer and some comment, I tried changing the code like bellow, but it still has the same problem...

```
// onChange={(e) => {
//   handleInput(index, e.nativeEvent.text);
      
onChangeText={(text) => {
  handleInput(index, text);
}}
```

---

node : 12.18.3

react native : 4.10.1

expo : 3.22.3

Comment: yes, you need to change onChange to onChangeText as react-native has slight difference in event listeners name when compared to React.

Comment: @devd, I changed the code like this `onChangeText={(text) => handleInput(index, text)}` but it still has the same problem...

Comment: Are you saying , you are loosing focus every time you press any key?

Comment: @devd, yes exactly, I lose a flashing vertical bar in the input area every time I press a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue occurred because your handle change function is wrong.

Please change...

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState({}); // change array to Object in useState.
```

Replace your handler with below function:

```
  function handleInput(index, text) {
    setNumber({ ...number, index: text });
  }
```

Comment: FYI..., working link of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brahmagupta-bm2zg?file=/src/App.js:464-548

Comment: thank you for your help, I changed the code like this following your advice `function handleInput(index, text) {setNumber((v) => ({ ...v, [index]: text })); } `,`function handleDelete(index) { setCount((v) => v - 1); setNumber((v) => {const ret = v.slice(); delete ret[index];return ret; });}`

Comment: If I am able to solve your issue,please mark the answer as correct and up vote -Thank You

Comment: after I change the code to a new one, I could resolve the problem to input text as useful, but if it's possible I hope to control the value with array not object because it is easier to use that value with the index of components.

Comment: ,Thank you for your help after I change the code as your updated one, I checked the value of the text(array of number) as `onChangeText={(text) => {
          handleInput(index, text);
          console.log(number);
        }}`  then although I can see the value in the input area,  the array of number is empty....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219623/discussion-between-devd-and-tio).

Answer (score 1):

React Native has onChangeText event on TextInput component can you try that one?

Comment: I tried to use `onChangeText`, but then it had an error like this `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.nativeEvent.text')`

Comment: and if I tried to change like this ` onChangeText={(e) => {
          handleInput(index, e);
        }}` TexiInput has the same problem...

Comment: onChangeText event not returning a parameter like "e". It returns text parameter that is written inside the TextInput component. In that case you must change it like                   onChangeText={text => handleInput(text)}

Comment: I changed the code like this`onChangeText={(text) => handleInput(index, text)}` but It has the same problem...